# How to define the link of footer bar icons? HTML iPhone App

Tags: iphone, html, hyperlink

Here is the code of my HTML iPhone app: http://summerblast.pt/iphone/code.html

I would like the icons of the bar to have a link. Lets say the first btn called "Emissão" will redirect to http://www.summerblast.pt/player.html

How can I do That?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your `ul` tag with the id `tabSelector` and under it you'll find the `li` with each tab. Surrounding the contents of each `li` is a `a` tag. If you add `href="[insert link to site here]"`, the contents of the `li` and therefor the icons will be clickable and link to the site.

An example of the edited tag would be this: `<a data-bind="click: selectTab" href = "www.google.com">` Notice the `href`

Here would be the full contents of the li for the first icon:

```
<li data-bind="attr: {'data-tabid': TabId}" data-tabid="1263865">
    <a data-bind="click: selectTab" href = "www.google.com">
        <img data-bind="attr: {src: TabId == $root.CurrentTab().topLevelSectionID ? TABU.getImageUrl(SelectedTabIcon, $element) : TABU.getImageUrl(TabIcon, $element)}" src="http://myapp.is/image/aHR0cDovL3RhYi1iYXNlLXVybC50aGVhcHBidWlsZGVyLmNvbS9hcHBidWlsZGVyYXNzZXRzL2Fzc2V0cy90YWJiYXJfaWNvbnMvaW9zX3NlbGVjdGVkLzMyMC9SZXNpc3RvcnMucG5n/0/0">
        <div data-bind="text: TabTitle">Emissão</div>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks! That was very useful! I've already updated the code :)

Just one more thing.. if you see the result of the page, there's an error with the play/stop btn... they are not working correctly... can you help me? (I'm not talking about the position... I'm saying that it appears the stop btn first but the audio doesnt play once you open the tab....)

Comment: @user2360382 I'm glad I could help. The polite thing to do on Stack Overflow is to up vote the answer and check off the check next to it (meaning that it answered your question). People *cough* me *cough* really appreciate it. :)

Comment: can you help me again with that prob?

Comment: @user2360382 What's the issue?

Comment: @user2360382 Never mind. I just realized you posted more in your comment.

Comment: @user2360382 It's a little unclear what you're saying. Could you post the updated code in a www.jsfiddle.net so it's easy to see?